# IE9 unable to see "files" on file input select box

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-upload

I'm trying to grab file information in IE9, and, for some reason I can't get at the file information.

What is wrong with my code? I've tried to break it down to [the simplest example I could](http://jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/dyh6H/). This works in Chrome, but, not IE:

```
<input name="file" type="file" onpropertychange="alert(this.files);" onchange="alert(this.files);" />
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

Comment: :/ In my non-simplified example I'm using this library that is supposed to fix this. https://github.com/MrSwitch/dropfile

Comment: I'll just vote to close this one and start over once I have a better test-case for the question...

Comment: Okay, put up a fiddle and we can take a look. Though that plugin seems to polyfill only the dropping of files in the browser, not accessing their data.

Answer (score 6):

The `File API` isn't implemented in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing you can do is to get the name of the selected file with **alert(this.value);**

If you need other informations you better check them on the server side as it's probably easy to manipulate them.